# Stack Overflow Usage Question

Tags: discussion, questions, comments

There are people who ask questions. We spend time in researching, using our experience and answering questions.

Those people never get back to us even after days. What should we do? We spent time trying to get the right answer to the questioner, but due to lack of response from other side, got no benefit in raising our reputation OR even finding out if our solution helped the person asking question.

Ideas?

Comment: Some people do that. You can't force them to do anything.

Comment: Look for clear, well-written questions and write answers. Upvotes from answers give much more rep than accepts.

Comment: why did someone down vote when it makes sense i think

Comment: @AstroCB - Why did you downvote my question ? Just because you had to make some Edits. I have seen far more worst english (probably due to haste in writing) in posted questions here.

Comment: @Rockoder [I did not downvote your question.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pDESo.png)

Comment: @AstroCB- sorry if you didn't and I misunderstood. Thanks for Editing question and your time :) Question was Down Voted again and it shows up as -2 now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need the author of the question to do a thing for you to get reputation for a good answer.  Anyone in the world with an account and 15 reputation can upvote a good answer to another user's questions.

More reputation is generated through upvotes than through accepts, and this nicely lines up with the site's values.  Answers that help a lot of people other than just the person that ask the question are rewarded much more than questions that only benefit the person asking the question.

Comment: If you think my question makes sense, please upvote.